# Value on Decision Tree plot

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-trees

After plotting a [sklearn decision](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.plot_tree.html) tree I check what it says in each box and there is one feature "value"
that I am not sure what it refers.

The first line will be the column and the value where it splits, the gini the "disorder" of the data and sample the number of samples in the node.

But value?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`value` represents the number of items in each class.

If you look at the top node, you should view it as:

There are:

- **35100** samples of class 0
- **16288** samples of class 1
- which sums up to **51388** samples total

Comment: Makes completely sense! Thanks for the answer!!

Comment: Apparently, you have the option to set values to percentages by setting the `proportion` flag to `True` (see: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_graphviz.html#sklearn.tree.export_graphviz)